# My Widget Build Again when focuse textfield?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using flutter 1.4.19.
In that when I tap on textfield it focus and my full widget I s reloading again. I don't want to reload that.

How to stop reload it except I call setstate() ??

Comment: It is happening because keyboard pops up and the build configuration changes. I don't think you can stop that.

Comment: Ok so have to save last my states because I am doing questions so it start again with first

Comment: yes.... for example, if you are using `TextEditingController` then instantiate it outside your build method.

Comment: Can I instantiate it in InitState?

Comment: yes....you can do that....

Comment: Ok I will try it. But I haven't added inputcontroller then still it rebuild Widget?

Comment: Rebuild will always happen in case of keyboard popping up or down

Comment: You saved my time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is many different cases where build method is rebuild:

- When MediaQuery object is create
- If screen is resize usually when Keyboard is appear and orientation change
- setState() call
- when you use Provider and notifyListener is called